# Where to find "prefs" for Beat Hazard?

Tags: beat-hazard

An update for Beat Hazard was released a couple of minutes ago: http://store.steampowered.com/news/4842/

Which my Steam client has rushed out to download, and, presumably, install.

The thing is, I can't figure out where they've put the features they're listing there.  (I really want the "remove quit screen" one :P)

When I go to the "options" page in the main menu, the only sections are "Audio & VSync", "Screen Resolution", and "languages", none of which seems relevant.

Is there some bonus hidden settings page somewhere?  Or maybe a config file I don't know about?  Or has the patch just not been installed, whatever Steam thinks?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Aha!  A friend of mine managed to track down the answer to this.

It turns out that you can *create* a config file to store these preferences:

> Version 1.7 will support a preference
>   file. You can use this to create
>   custom settings for Beat Hazard.
>
> You need to create a text file called
>   BeatHazardPref.txt
>
> The file needs to be in your
>   'AppData\Beat Hazard' folder. The
>   position of this folder is different
>   depending on which version of windows
>   you're using.
>
> To find the correct folder, search for
>   BeatHazardRez.sav on your computer.
>   Put the file there.
>
> Example File:
>   =============
>      `CustomRez 0 800 600; 
>
>      NoRSS; 
>
>      ConstVolume; 
>
>      end;`
>
> (note you need a ';' at the end of
>   each line)

Text taken from post with full details/list of commands here: http://forums.steampowered.com/forums/showthread.php?t=1276610

I wound up with this:

```
ConstVolume;
ThanksButNoThanks;
end;
```